# Chartjs - line chart display with addData() is bugged?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When I'm using an array to fill in my line chart it's kinda doing something odd.
I noticed when I add 7 new points it works properly like this:[image: 7 points working chart]

But when I add 8(or more) new points instead of 7 the result is this:
[image: 8 points broken chart]

below you can find my code:

```
<script>

var arrayGegevens = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

var data = 
{
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Machine activity",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: []
        }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, 
{
bezierCurve: false,
animation: false    
});

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) // 8 should be arrayGegevens.Length (=20)
{
    myLineChart.addData([arrayGegevens[i]['MachineStatus']], arrayGegevens[i]['Time']); 
}

 </script>
```

So am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was with the length of the labels (2015-3-24 14:55:00). I substringed them down to 14:55 and now I can fit way more of them in 1 line chart!